# Compute expectation using tower property

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Imagine I want to compute $E[f(X,Y)]$ where $f$ is a suitable function and $X,Y$ random variables.

If $X$ and $Y$ are correlated, let us say $X=g(Y)$ or even in my case $X_t$ and $Y_t$ are stochastic processes and $Y_t=g(X_{\cdot})$. My question is: am I allowed to do
$$E[f(X,Y)]= E[E[f(X,y)|y=Y]]?$$
in my case, now the law of $X$ is known and it is easy to compute $E[f(X,y)|y=Y]$ and then insert $y=Y$ and compute the rest.

The point is, I know the law of $X$ if $Y$ is fixed given, and I fully know the law of $Y$, but I am not 100% sure that this method is correct, I feel I don't use the correlation part. The fact that they are (or not) correlated, does it affect the method of computing it?

Thanks for the support!

Comment: It is correct, the correlation between $X$ and $Y$ is captured by the inner expectation which is with respect to conditioned pdf of $X$ given $Y$ (assuming the densities exist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is correct. It follows from the tower property that

$$\mathbb{E}(f(X,Y))=\mathbb{E}\big( \mathbb{E}(f(X,Y) \mid \mathcal{F}) \big)$$

for any $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$. In particular, we can choose $\mathcal{F} := \sigma(Y)$ the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $Y$. Moreover, we know from the factorization lemma that there exists a function $h$ (depending on $f$) such that

$$\mathbb{E}(f(X,Y) \mid Y)  := \mathbb{E}(f(X,Y) \mid \sigma(Y)) = h(Y).$$

Usually, this is denoted by

$$h(y) = \mathbb{E}(f(X,Y) \mid Y=y).$$

Combining the equalities yields

$$\mathbb{E}(f(X,Y)) = \mathbb{E}\big( \mathbb{E}(f(X,Y) \mid Y=y) \big|_{y=Y} \big).$$